# response.getWriter(); what is the task of this method?

Tags: servlets

I know this question has been asked before several times. But the answers are not satisfactory. I know getWriter method returns an object of PrintWriter class.Everyone has answered what it returns but I want to know what is used for?

Comment: What part of the [PrintWriter javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) are you struggling with?  The key is that the output is tied to the output that the servlet can send back to the requester.

Comment: And how about the [ServletResponse javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ever you request something from Client to Server it must maintain a format. Now in J2EE we bind the request information into an object and send it to server. That's why we need a HttpServletRequest reference in Service class. Now the server has the raw data which should be modify/calcuated/ whatever the code is that is to send back again to client and the result is kept in an object of response type.Thats why needed HttpServletResponse reference. Now in HttpServletResponse there is a method named getWriter() which binds the result into object and returns an object of PrintWriter class. Hope this helped you.